# How to show bootstrap pop up on Delete link in asp.net mvc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

My Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
   public ActionResult DeleteStudent(int id)
   {
       Student s = db.Students.Include("Cla").Include("Section").Where(e => e.Id ==
                               id).SingleOrDefault();
       db.Students.Remove(s);
       db.SaveChanges();
       return RedirectToAction("AllStudent", "Admin");
   }
```

The delete function is working properly. But not showing the popup alert.When i click on a delete link data will be deleted but pop up box is not shown.Can anyone resolve this issue. I also used a pagedlist package in that view.

My View:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<TakGayeYArHumB.Models.Student>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
<table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Options</th>
                    </tr>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                       <tr> 
                           <td>
                              <div class="btn-group">
                                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-                             
                            primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                       Action <span class="caret"></span>
                                     </button>
                                     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "UpdateStudent", new { id = item.Id })</li>
                                                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteStudent", new { @id = "form-message-delete" })</li>

                                                             </ul>

                                                         </div>

                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                             }
                                    </table>
```

My Javacript code:

```
    <script>
     function messageDelete(index) {
       bootbox.dialog({
        message: "Are you sure you want to delete the message ?",
        title: "Delete Message Confirmation",
        buttons: {
         success: {
             label: "Continue",
             className: "btn-success",
             callback: function deletemember() {
                $('.messageId').val(index);
                $('#form-message-delete').submit();
            },
            danger: {
                label: "Cancel",
                className: "btn-danger",
                callback: function () {
                    bootbox.hideAll();
                }
              }
            }
          }
       });
      };
    </script>
```

Comment: and you are directly sending delete request to controller action method.. You must send `ajax` request if user surely wants to delete.

Comment: I dont know how to send request through ajax. can you help me how to send request through ajax?